# Jquery animation and css right and left

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is working fine on the first click (moving the left border to the middle)  but on the second it does not and I cant figure why. I know that I can use another solution but I want to know why the right:50% is not working.  Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
 $( "button" ).click(function(){
  
     screenWidth = $("html").width() /2;
      positionLeft = Math.round($(".container").offset().left) 
      
  if ( positionLeft < screenWidth) {  
     $(".container").animate({
   left: "50%"
   }, 1000);
  } else if (positionLeft == screenWidth) {     
   $(".container").animate({
   right: "50%"
   }, 1000);  
  }
 });
 
});
```

```css
.container{
  background-color:black;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;    
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>debugging</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>         
  <button>click</button> 
</body>


<script>


</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already walking in one direction, you have to turn around...

If you want to *position* an element, you can declare only the offset from "the same sides" (top-left / bottom-right). Just reset the opposite with the `auto`-value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
         
  $( "button" ).click(function(){
    screenWidth = $("html").width() /2;
    positionLeft = Math.round($(".container").offset().left)
           
    if ( positionLeft < screenWidth) {
      $(".container").css('right', 'auto');
      $(".container").animate({
        left: "50%"
      }, 1000);
    } else if (positionLeft == screenWidth) {
      $(".container").css('left', 'auto');
      $(".container").animate({
        right: "50%"
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color:black;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>debugging</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <button>click</button> 
</body>


<script>


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: very helpful man, however when I put the auto, the animation starts from 0 not from the current position. any clues how to solve this?

Comment: @Noobest It depends on what you expect... In your question you've just asked for *why the right:50% is not working*. Explain your problem a bit further, so that we can help.

Comment: when you click the second time , the animation starts from 0% to 50%right instead from the current right position the element have to 50%

Comment: If i understand you right, you have to calculate the right-offset manually and apply it the container. So, just insert `$(".container").css('right', screenWidth - containerWidth);` right after `$(".container").css('left', 'auto');`.

Answer (score 1):

You have more then one problem in your code:

This condition may not be `true` because of the `Math.round` you are using:

```
positionLeft == screenWidth
```

Just use `else` without a condition.

You animate `left` at the first click, and `right` at the second click, but then the `left` and the `right` style are both set! Either reset `left` and then use `right`, or just use one of both.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/438o3u6x/

Answer (score 0):

You have to just change this condition:

```
$( "button" ).click(function(){

           screenWidth = $("html").width() /2;
         positionLeft = Math.round($(".container").offset().left)   

        if ( positionLeft < screenWidth) {      
        $(".container").animate({
            left: "50%"
            }, 1000);
        } else if (positionLeft == screenWidth) {                   
            $(".container").animate({
            left: "0%"
            }, 1000);   
        }
    });
```

Change right: "50%" with left: "0%"

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vh67jwte/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
 $( "button" ).click(function(){
  
     screenWidth = parseInt($("html").width() /2, 10);
      positionLeft = Math.round($(".container").offset().left) 
      
  if ( positionLeft < screenWidth) {  
     $(".container").css({left : '0%'}).animate({
   left: "50%"
   }, 1000);
  } else if (positionLeft == screenWidth) {     
   $(".container").css({ left : 'calc(100% - 20%)'} ).animate({
   left: "49%"
   }, 1000);  
  }
 });
 
});
```

```css
.container{
  background-color:black;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;    
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>debugging</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>         
  <button>click</button> 
</body>


<script>


</script>
</html>
```

You need a different approach to this. `right` doesn't seem to work. So first use `css` to set the element to `100%` left, using `calc` as a nifty way to subtract the width of the element. then return to left `49%` (to reset animation from the left) which gives you the animation you want I guess?

Answer (score 0):

1. For the first: use same finction for get integer values of
   `screenWidth` and `positionLeft`.

   `screenWidth|0 == Math.floor(screenWidth)
    Math.round(screenWidth)
    Math.ceil(screenWidth)`

There are three variants, and you must use this one.

2. And second: you can add `console.log('step1')`, `console.log('step2')` for view result of your click function because you css solution is bad.